# Symmetric Channel

Tags: coding-theory

I was studying Coding Theory and I realized that when we design probabilistic channel, one of the important criteria is that the channel has to be symmetric, i.e each of the digits $a_i\in A$ where $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ has same error probability $p$.

Why is same error probability important in designing a coding channel?

Comment: Channels (at least those in telecommunications) are usually not *designed*. I would rather say that they are *modelled*. In other words, the physical channel is what it is, and we simply try to model it mathematically to better understand what kind of errors the channel is likely to produce, and how we are to alleviate those.

Comment: And not all channels are symmetric. Due to the nature of radiowaves, the symmetry assumption is a useful tool there. But the ways we modulate the signals may create certain asymmetries even there.